# How to uninstall a compiler on mac?

Tags: macos, visual-studio-code, gcc, compiler-errors, clang

First, I want to check all the c++ compilers I have installed on my mac.
I most probably have Clang and GCC both. So now I want to delete GCC.
please tell me how to do these 2 things.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You probably have clang pretending to be gcc (type `gcc --version` to check). But there's no clear definition of "installed" on Mac. You can place a compiler anywhere and run it from there (and I often have). But you can look in each part of your PATH (`echo $PATH`), and see what is in each directory. Or you can just use `which clang` and `which gcc` to see what would be picked up by default. You could even try `locate gcc` to find copies in some less usual locations that won't be run by default like versioned copies in homebrew (the first time you run this, it will tell you how to start the locate service).

But I expect that you really only have one compiler installed (clang). That's the normal situation. It just has hardlinks to gcc for backward compatibility.